# Traer registros 5 meses atras SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo un script el cual es el siguiente

```
SELECT 
 c.NoCuenta
,c.FechaUltimoMovimiento 

FROM CUENTAS c
```

Y quiero que me traiga unicamente las cuentas que la ultima fecha de movimiento fue 5 meses atras a partir de la fecha actual

por ejemplo si las cuentas tuvieron movimiento en enero (5 meses atras de la fecha actual) solo quiero que me muestre esas de enero y no me traiga de mas atras

Como puedo realizar eso?

Comment: algo muy similar a `WHERE FechaUltimoMovimiento >= DATEADD(MONTH,-5,GETDATE())` (te dejo la tarea de pensar cómo hacer para que evitar que la hora te traiga un problema)

Comment: creo que lo pusiste al contrario, ya que por ejemplo tomando en cuenta que estamos en mayo y le estoy restando 5 meses, necesito me traiga solo las cuentas que la ultima fecha de transaccion fue en Enero (5 meses atras)

Comment: un ejemplo claro? datos de entrada, datos de salida, que fue lo que intentaste??? es un simple where, si sabemos bien que necesitas...

Comment: @Beterson hola!, con el ejemplo que das de:  hoy (25/05/2023) y que quieres los registros del 25/01/2023 son 4 meses  `SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,-4,GETDATE())` esta consulta trae exactamene ese dato, solo bastaria el tema de las horas, minutos y segundos, como ya comentaron.

Comment: Si estamos en mayo, cinco meses atrás nos remonta a diciembre, no a enero. Tampoco queda claro si quieres los registros de exactamente cinco meses atrás, o los de todo el mes, pues la redacción es confusa. Por favor [edit] tu pregunta y aclara esos puntos. Encontrás más información en [ask].